# Python for 32 bit Oracle

Tags: python, pyodbc

I have python 3.9 (64-bit) but anaconda is 32-bit. I am trying to connect to my internal oracle databases which are 32 bit.

When trying to use pyodbc (in Spyder), I am getting the following error:

```
OperationalError: ('08004', '[08004] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12154:
TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified\n (12154)
(SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I am assuming this is due to the 64-bit and 32-bit conflict.
I tried researching online but couldnt find where could I download the python 32-bit.
Is there a work around for this?

Comment: I suggest you just use 32-bit Python. I don't use the 64-bit version to avoid precisely the problems you're encountering.

Comment: Yeah. where do i download the 32-bit python from?

Comment: From [www.python.org](https://www.python.org).

Comment: Are you able to connect to the internal oracle database using pure odbc (without pyodbc)? On a linux based system you could try isql for example.

Comment: how do i try to do the internal oracle database using pure odbc

Comment: You can use the command isql followed by the name of the datasource.